# ModifierKeys.None not working. ctrl+add triggers "ctrl+add" and  "add"

Tags: .net, wpf, keyboard, keydown

I got a little problem I just can't figure out:

I want two different keyboard shortcuts to work. The one being `ctrl+add`, the other being `add` alone. The problem is, whenever I press `ctrl+add` the `add` command is executed also.

I tried it with the following code (I used KeyDown event):

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.Add)
        something();

if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None && e.Key == Key.Add)
        someOther();
```

Comment: i ended up doing the following: i set e.Handled to true in the command with the control modifier, and in the other command i added " && !e.Handled" to the if bracket....is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Your sample code could be more compact, but it should work as expected. No need for setting e.Handled.

Comment: how could it be more compact then :) ? And without setting e.Handled it always executes something() and someOther() when pressing ctrl+add, when only something() is wanted to be executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Add)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
    {  
        something();  
    }
    else if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
    {  
        someOther();
    }
}
```